# Oracle DB won't allow users to query tables

Tags: oracle, oracle-xe

I am on Windows XP running Oracle 10G XE Edition.
After running a defrag & cleanup process, I have not been able to access any of the objects on the database.

A quick check

```
set lines110
col strtd hea 'STARTED' 
col instance_name for a8 hea 'INSTANCE'
col host_name for a15 hea 'HOSTNAME' 
col version for a10 



select instance_name, version, host_name, status
, database_status, to_char(startup_time,'DD-MON-YYYY HH:MI:SS') strtd 
from v$instance;
```

**returns this**

```
INSTANCE VERSION    HOSTNAME        STATUS       DATABASE_STATUS   STARTED
-------- ---------- --------------- ------------ ----------------- ----------------------------------------------------
xe       10.2.0.1.0 DT8775C    MOUNTED      ACTIVE            03-DEC-2010 11:38:00


If I use this command, it throws the following error.
SQL> ALTER DATABASE OPEN;
ALTER DATABASE OPEN
*
*ERROR at line 1:*
ORA-16014: log 2 sequence# 679 not archived, no available destinations
ORA-00312: online log 2 thread 1:
'D:\ORACLEEXE\APP\ORACLE\FLASH_RECOVERY_AREA\XE\ONLINELOG\O1_MF_2_4JD5RZC0_.LOG'
```

How can I fix this situation?
There are zero files in the 
"D:\ORACLEEXE\APP\ORACLE\FLASH_RECOVERY_AREA\XE\ONLINELOG\" folder.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure this belongs on SERVERFAULT, but to get you going for now:

It appears the database is in ARCHIVELOG mode and you have not supplied a location to store the archived log files. A quick fix, assuming you don't need the recovery protection that archive logging gives you is to try this:

```
sqlplus / as sysdba
SQL> shutdown immediate;
SQL> startup mount;
SQL> ALTER DATABASE NOARCHIVELOG;
SQL> ALTER DATABASE OPEN;
```

If you do want to keep your archived redo logs, then you'll need entries like this in your database parameters:

```
alter system set log_archive_dest_1='location=d:\oraclexe\app\oracle\...';
alter system set log_archive_dest_state_1=enable;
```

Comment: I'll have to test this out. What I did was a complete reinstall of Oracle XE, which was something I originally intended to avoid.

Comment: If this is the problem, you'll run into it again ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like in your cleanup process you may have deleted the .LOG files.  I assume you've emptied the trash and can't restore them?

Comment: Hi Roger,
That's correct. Can I get it up and running? It is a development only machine and short of re-installing Oracle XE, are there any options available?

Comment: The only option you have is to drop and recreate the database. If you can't do this through the XE frontend, you'll need to do it through SQL*Plus, see the admin guide for details: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14231/create.htm#i1017640